# Symfony2/Doctrine2 One-To-Many same object twice

Tags: doctrine, symfony

My current Client-Entity has an unloading and a loading Area, which are both ClientArea-Entities.

```
namespace ACME\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sorien\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientArea",mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    public $unloading_areas; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientArea",mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    public $loading_areas; 
}

class ClientArea
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     */
    public  $client;
}
```

This does not work because client can only map 1 association.
How can i map the relation properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create entity relations you need to have keys to use when joining tables. Your Client class should have an `id` key defined and you need to initialize collections, like this:

```
class Client
{
    //....

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientArea", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    public $unloading_areas; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientArea", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    public $loading_areas; 

    public function __construct() {
        // Initialize collections
        $this->unloading_areas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->loading_areas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ....
}
```

Your ClientArea class should then look something like this:

```
class ClientArea
{
    // ....

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="int", nullable=false)
     */
    private $clientId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public  $client;

    // ....
}
```

Now, those two entities should be mapped correctly.
To learn more about association mappings in Doctrine, read article here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Hope this helps.